# make request parameter value as selected in dropdown when page load in jsp

Tags: jsp

in the session i have a string like "apple" when i go to other page in that dynamic dropdown is there, by default dropdown list should compare with session string i.e "apple" if it found in that list make that as selected. please help me

for Example see below, this is dynamic dropdown fetched from db with sql query **select fruit from foods** 
Connection conn = null;

```
conn = new DBConnection().getMyConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select fruit from foods");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
Select Fruit : <select name="fruit" id="fruit"> 
        <% while (rs.next()) { %>
            <option value="0">select fruit</option>
            <option value="<%=rs.getString("fruit")%>">
            <%=rs.getString("fruit")%></option>
</select>

**output:**

    <select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="0">select fruit</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="guva">guva</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    </select>
```

when i load the page by default it should be like below dropdown i.e, apple should be selected:
**Expected Output :**

```
   <select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="0">select fruit</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="guva">guva</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The expected output doesn't select any option. The syntax for selecting an option is `<option value="apple" selected>apple</option>`. You also really need to stop having Java and scriptlets in your JSPs. Put the DB stuff into a controller written as a servlet, store Java beans in the request, then forward to a JSP and use the JSP EL and the JSTL to only generate HTML in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

Firstly you need to write your own code, this community is not for getting your homework done.

Now, to answer your question, firstly write java code in class and pass the result as list in jsp using session.

now to get "apple" by default selected, if possible write logic in servlet to get "apple" as first element in list and then pass.

My advice, try and go threw some tutorials by your self it will surely help clarify things.

Hope this helps.